# Python: How to sort dictionary value using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file, dictionary

I have two .txt files where it reads them into a dictionary. I want to have an option where I can sort the value (third tab in the files) in the dictionary from highest to lowest using regex.

Here are my files: 
**file1.txt**

```
file Marvel/GuardiansOfGalaxy 300 1
file DC/Batman 504 1
file GameOfThrones 900 0
file DC/Superman 200 1
file Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342 0
```

**file2.txt**

```
file Science/Biology 200 1
file Math/Calculus 342 0
file Psychology 324 1
file Anthropology 234 0
file Science/Chemistry 444 1
```

This is the supposed output:

```
Game of Thrones: 900
DC/Batman: 404
Science/Chemistry: 444
Marvel/CaptainAmerica 342
Math/Calculus 342
...
```

This is what my code looks like so far. I'm having trouble displaying the data in a sorted manner based on the value(third tab) using regex. The read function works. Now It just all depends on displaying the sorted dictionary:

```
def read():
    pattern = re.compile(r"file\.py (.+).*? (\d+) \d+")

    data_files = []
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        with open(file, 'r') as filenames:
            data_files.append(dict(pattern.findall(filenames.read())))
    return data_files
```

This is where I tried to sort the values from dictionary using re.findall and map(int,), but I get a TypeError. I couldn't identify where I went wrong. This is the part I need help on mostly:

```
def display(data_files):
    for lines in data_files:
        # print(lines)
        pattern_sort = re.findall(r"file\.py (.+).*? (\d+) \d+", data_files)
        print(sorted(lines, key=lambda x: (map(int, pattern_sort))))
```

I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need regex? Why not just split it, grab the 3rd value, place it into sort(), then order the values based on that?

Comment: @FailSafe I'm using regex to parse the data for later uses

Comment: Sorry. I should be more specific. Why do you need regex for this particular task? It can be done, but might not be the optimal solution

Comment: I need regex to find the amount of views in the line and then sort it from the others. I’m having trouble displaying the sort using map on my display function. I guess for my display function I can just sort and grab the third data, but how can you do that without changing my read function?

Comment: Is there a reason you are putting in a `dict` instead of a `list`? If you put it in a list of `namedtuples` you could sort on that field with ease. In general a `dict` is not designed to be sorted. (Though you can use an `OrderedDict`).  In a couple hours I can code a solution but I just want to know if you need to use a `dict`.

Comment: I need to read the files and turn it into a dictionary. Do you think OrderedDict will help me order them but I also have to use regex to parse the data to put the views from highest to lowest and alphabetical order (for sort).

Comment: You can't use a dictionary if you expect to use the 3rd value as the key. You have duplicate keys in that instance and python dictionaries don't permit that. It'll just overwrite the previously entered dictionary item with of the same key. You can get around this by creating a list and adding multiple elements to a dictionary value list.

Comment: Does [this](https://repl.it/repls/MildGoldenStartups) work for you? Note that I had to replace tabs with `|||` since repl.it isn't allowing me to use tab characters in files.

Comment: @ctwheels Sort of. The third value, in this case, is not in highest to lowest. Is there a way I can turn it into a dictionary afterward?

Comment: @smokingpenguin not sure I understand what you mean. If you add `reverse=True` to the sort, does that produce the results you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is one way of producing the results you're asking for using a dictionary. The only catch is that since a dictionary doesn't allow duplicate keys, you need the dictionary values to be lists (containing the duplicate key values).

**Please note I had to change tab character to `|||` since repl.it isn't allowing me to use the tab character in files.** You would have to replace `|||` with `\t` in the script below.

[See it run here](https://repl.it/repls/MildGoldenStartups)

```
import glob
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict

d = defaultdict(list)

def read():
  for files in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(files, 'r') as f:
      for line in f:
        r = line.rstrip('\n').split('|||')
        d[r[2]].append(r)

def display(d):
  od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), reverse=True))
  for k,v in od.items(): print(k,v)

read()
display(d)
```

The output for the script above is below:

```
900 [['file', 'GameOfThrones', '900', '0']]
504 [['file', 'DC/Batman', '504', '1']]
444 [['file', 'Science/Chemistry', '444', '1']]
342 [['file', 'Marvel/CaptainAmerica', '342', '0'], ['file', 'Math/Calculus', '342', '0']]
324 [['file', 'Psychology', '324', '1']]
300 [['file', 'Marvel/GuardiansOfGalaxy', '300', '1']]
234 [['file', 'Anthropology', '234', '0']]
200 [['file', 'DC/Superman', '200', '1'], ['file', 'Science/Biology', '200', '1']]
```

---

### Different Outputs

Changing `print(k,v)` to another format gets you different output as you've noted in the comments below. For example:

```
print(k, [x[1] for x in v])
```

This results in the following:

```
900 ['GameOfThrones']
504 ['DC/Batman']
444 ['Science/Chemistry']
342 ['Marvel/CaptainAmerica', 'Math/Calculus']
324 ['Psychology']
300 ['Marvel/GuardiansOfGalaxy']
234 ['Anthropology']
200 ['DC/Superman', 'Science/Biology']
```

Comment: Is there a way to just show the second and third value? I think this is what I can use regex to just display them or no?

Comment: @smokingpenguin you can change the way `display` prints the output

Comment: The biggest reason why I decided to use regex is to make sure that the specific format of the string is recognized in the files. If a string in the text file is like "hello.py /Marval/Cast 43 4" That would not be counted. Does that make sense?

Comment: @smokingpenguin it's not clear. You should update your question to include all relevant information. We've both solved the question based on the information you provided in the question.

Comment: @ctwheels my bad. Thank you so much for the help so far. Also, the link provided is given me a syntax error

Comment: @smokingpenguin you probably caught it while I was testing a new output out. Try it now with `print(k, [x[1] for x in v])` as the output

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As *FailSafe* said there is no reason to use `regex` for this so I used `split` instead.  I will add a `regex` solution to this problem later but here is how to do it without `regex`.

```
import glob
from collections import namedtuple

# A lightweight object.
# Makes it easier to sort.
Entry = namedtuple("Entry", "name views")

def read():
    data_files = []
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        with open(file, 'r') as infile:
            for line in infile.read().splitlines():
                # For each line in the file

                # Split apart our line
                line = line.split(' ')
                # Create an Entry object with our name and views
                # and add it to our data_files.
                data_files.append(Entry(line[1], int(line[2])))
    return data_files
result = read()

# We want to sort based on views so return the views.
def sort_meth(x):
    return x.views
    # If you want to sort by views then name you can do
    # return (x.views, x.name)

# Sort our result
result.sort(key=sort_meth, reverse=True)
for entry in result: # Print each entry
  print(entry.name, entry.views)
```

Comment: smokingpenguin is the original poster. No worries. I like both of the solutions posted.

Comment: Haha, no worries mate. Hopefully he understands everything.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse This works as well! I still would like to see how regex can come into play with your code.

Comment: @smokingpenguin If the dictionary solution works for you, you may want to stick with what you know. With regex, is it safe to assume the end of your string/line will always be the same and only the beginning will change?

Comment: @smokingpenguin seriously, here it is so unnecessary. You'd be doing extra work for no reason. Use regex where appropriate. Yes, we know you want to learn, but sometimes there are times where extra steps are just kind of silly. The regex for this would be entirely to simplistic for anyone with experience to take on for a 2 second post.

Comment: That's true. Thank you so much for the help though. It helped me understand and think of a better design logic.